# Windows 10 not fully shutting down

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, reboot

I have had this problem show up on multiple computers with different arrangements of hardware: a laptop I used to own, a computer I built for work with an Intel CPU, and the computer I'm typing this on with an AMD Ryzen CPU.

Occasionally (not every time), when the computer reboots to install updates the reboot will stop halfway. The power light will still be on and the keyboard and mouse will still be powered, but the monitor screen is black and the computer is unresponsive to any stimulus.

Why is this happening? I have done many searches to try and research causes of this and have turned up many answers, none of them helpful. My BIOS is up to date. Some suggested reverting the Intel Management Engine driver, which doesn't apply to the AMD computer. Some suggested turning off fast boot, but I've seen that that option doesn't affect restarts, only shutdowns. This happens most often restarts. In particular, the work computer is almost never shut down, so it only experiences reboots to install updates. Literally the only thing all these computers have in common is Windows 10. The laptop only started having this problem when upgraded from Win 7 -> Win 10.

I've checked many of the "similar questions" on this site, and none of them seem to be asking about my exact problem. I'm at my wit's end here and don't know what else I can do to fix this stupidly ridiculous problem.

Comment: The first step diagnosing shutdown issues is to make sure ALL of your drivers and firmware are fully up to date. If your computer was built by a brand (eg, Dell, HP, ASUS, etc) go to their support site and download the latest available drivers. However, because you've updated from Windows 7 to 10, there may not be drivers available for Windows 10.

Comment: Only the laptop went from 7 -> 10. The two desktops were built new and I installed Win 10 on them. I've tried to the best of my ability to make sure drivers are up to date (particularily checking the motherboard maker's website), so if it's a problem with that I would need more specific help because I don't know what to look for.